# How do I install MonoDevelop on my Mac?

Tags: macos, monodevelop

I just downloaded MonoDevelop for my Mac, but I cannot figure out how to install it.

Does anyone know *exactly* what to type in the terminal to get it to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recently updated Mono 1.2.6 package for MacOS X contains [Imendio's Native Gtk+ for OSX](http://developer.imendio.com/projects/gtk-macosx), Gtk# and MonoDevelop 0.18.1 with Mac support. It is now available from [Mono's downloads page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

It appears that you have to run all three of these installs to get it to work:

- [Mono 2.2_5 Framework - Universal](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/archive/2.2/macos-10-universal/5/MonoFramework-2.2_5.macos10.novell.universal.dmg)
- [MonoDevelop 2.0 Alpha 2](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/monodevelop/MonoDevelop-1.9.1-1.dmg)
- [Cocoa# 0.9.4 source](http://go-mono.com/sources/cocoa-sharp/cocoa-sharp-0.9.4.tar.bz2)

Comment: Not any more - they've removed it, and the only way to get it is to build from source, apparently. Google had this page as top hit.

Answer (score 1):

this link might be helpful for new comers. 
[Mono:OsX](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX#Using_Mono_on_MacOS_X)

follow the link below if you are interested in Building Monodevelop in os X:

[Building mono develop](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X)

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Studio may be installed using Homebrew.

> For Mac and Windows, you can download Xamarin Studio which is a bundle of MonoDevelop along with Xamarin iOS/Android plugins and branding.
>
> – [Download | MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/).

There is a Homebrew Cask for Xamarin Studio.
The installation can be done as follows:

```
$ brew install Caskroom/cask/xamarin-studio
```

This question might be useful: [How to use Homebrew's version of Mono with Xamarin - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553233/).